# How to disable the PDF preview in the file block by default

Tags: customization, uploads, block-editor, options

when I insert a PDF file with the file block on the page it always opens to me with the preview of the file with the pdf viewer, so I have to put the check to disable it.  Is there a way to have that tick disabled by default when inserting the block and to be able to enable it only when necessary?  I will have to upload files often but I don't want to have to turn it off all the time, I just want the file link and the download button, I hope it can be preset somehow.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, this setting is not yet provided but several users have requested it (https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/34825) and there is work to implement this.

Comment: hello thanks for the answer, unfortunately @will there is no news, it is annoying especially when you have to upload many files having to disable embedding, I hope to find a solution